# Calling a Component from a View Cell - Can I? Should I? CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, components, cakephp-3.0, correctness

So I am looking to call a Component from a View Cell in CakePHP 3.0. From what I underdstand, a view cell is supposed to be like a mini controller..? If so, does this mean it is okay call a component from one of these or is that bad practice?

I feel that this may be bad practice as it doesnt live in the same namespace making it harder to get to the components.. But if it isnt bad practice.. Is this an oversight maybe?

Anyway the main question, what is the "right way" of getting to a component inside a view cell?

Thanks all, Ash.

**ADDITIONAL**

Ive noticed this in the [documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/cells.html#implementing-the-cell), but still doesnt quite answer my question.

> Cell templates have an isolated scope that does not share the same
>   View instance as the one used to render template and layout for the
>   current controller action or other cells. Hence they are unaware of
>   any helper calls made or blocks set in the action’s template / layout
>   and vice versa.

Comment: Will be easier to answer if you show a working solution. In short though: no.